# Can we prove $1\neq 2$ using intuitionistic methods?

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic

Can we prove $1\neq 2$ using intuitionistic methods? It is trivial to prove conventionally starting from Peano's Axioms, but it seems to require a proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Assume $S(0)=S(S(0))$.
>
> One of the Peano axioms say that $S(x)=S(y) \to x=y$, so we immediately conclude $0=S(0)$. But this contradicts the axiom $\forall x(0\ne S(x))$.
>
> Thus $S(0)\ne S(S(0))$.

This reasoning is intuitionistically valid. It is **not proof by contradiction**, but merely the negation introduction rule which *is* allowed in intuitionistic logic:

$$ \frac{\Gamma, P\vdash \bot}{\Gamma \vdash \neg P}\;\neg\,\text{-intro} $$

Actual proof by contradiction (which is not allowed in intuitionistic logic) would be
$$ \frac{\Gamma, \neg P\vdash \bot}{\Gamma\vdash P}\;\text{r.a.a.}$$

Comment: You assume $S(0)=S(S(0))$, then obtain the contradiction $0=S(0) \land 0\neq S(0)$. Is this not a proof by contradiction?

Comment: Or more precisely, if you start from $\Gamma$ and $\neg P$ and deduce a contradiction, you can conclude $\neg(\neg P)$. What intuitionistic logic does not allow you to do is go from $\neg(\neg P)$ to $P$ in general.

Comment: @DanChristensen: No, _as I explain in this very answer_, that is not proof by contradiction.

Comment: It would be a proof by contradiction in conventional logic, would it not?

Comment: @DanChristensen: Some texts might describe it as such, because in classical logic there is no urgent need to distinguish between negation introduction and RAA.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin So, it is not proof by contradiction that is banned by intuitionistic methods, but the elimination of double negation that is banned. Once you get to $\neg \neg P$, you would be stuck, correct?

Comment: @DanChristensen: I would not say “stuck”; just “not able to get from there to $P$”.

Comment: @DanChristensen You also want to be careful about the term “proof by contradiction”; if you are talking at the level of basic logic, then it has a precise meaning that is more restrictive than the common usage, as indicated correctly by Henning Makholm. Generally, we think of “proof by contradiction” as anything in which we assume the negation of what we want to prove and deduce a contradiction. But formally, it generally refers to a proof of the form $\Bigl( (\Gamma,\neg P)\to (Q\wedge \neg Q)\Bigr)\implies P$, and this argument is not of that type.

Comment: @DanChristensen [This post by Andrej Bauer](http://math.andrej.com/2010/03/29/proof-of-negation-and-proof-by-contradiction/) and [this one by Bob Harper](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2017/03/04/a-proof-by-contradiction-is-not-a-proof-that-derives-a-contradiction/) both discuss the mistaken abuse of the term "proof by contradiction" in connection with intuitionistic logic.

Comment: When intuitionists say double negation elimination (or excluded middle) are "banned", what they mean is that they aren't given to you as an axiom.  There are plenty of $P$ for which $\vdash \lnot \lnot P \to P$ and there are no $P$ such that $\vdash \lnot (\lnot \lnot P \to P)$

Comment: In particular, as @DanielV alludes to, $\neg\neg(\neg\neg P\to P)$ is intuitionistically provable for every $P$.